# OpenGL Camera vectors

Tags: c++, math, opengl

I have a very rudimentary camera which generates 3 vectors for use with `gluLookAt(...)` the problem is I'm not sure if this is correct, I adapted code from something my lecturer showed us (I think he got it from somewhere).

This actually works until you spin the mouse round in circles than camera starts to rotate around the z-axis. Which shouldn't happen as the mouse coords are only attached to the pitch and yaw not the roll.

Camera

```
// Camera.hpp

#ifndef MOOT_CAMERA_INCLUDE_HPP
#define MOOT_CAMERA_INCLUDE_HPP

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <Moot/Platform.hpp>
#include <Moot/Vector3D.hpp>

namespace Moot
{
    class Camera : public boost::noncopyable
    {
    protected:

        Vec3f m_position, m_up, m_right, m_forward, m_viewPoint;
        uint16_t m_height, m_width;

    public:


        Camera()
        {
            m_forward = Vec3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            m_right = Vec3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            m_up = Vec3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        void setup(uint16_t setHeight, uint16_t setWidth)
        {
            m_height = setHeight;
            m_width = setWidth;
        }

        void move(float distance)
        {
            m_position += (m_forward * distance);
        }


        void addPitch(float setPitch)
        {
            m_forward = (m_forward * cos(setPitch) + (m_up * sin(setPitch)));
            m_forward.setNormal();

                    // Cross Product
            m_up = (m_forward / m_right) * -1;
        }


        void addYaw(float setYaw)
        {
            m_forward = ((m_forward * cos(setYaw)) - (m_right * sin(setYaw)));
            m_forward.setNormal();

                    // Cross Product
            m_right = m_forward / m_up;
        }


        void addRoll(float setRoll)
        {
            m_right = (m_right * cos(setRoll) + (m_up * sin(setRoll)));
            m_right.setNormal();

                    // Cross Product
            m_up = (m_forward / m_right) * -1;
        }

        virtual void apply() = 0;       

    }; // Camera
} // Moot

#endif
```

Snippet from update cycle

```
    // Mouse movement
    m_camera.addPitch((float)input().mouseDeltaY() * 0.001);
    m_camera.addYaw((float)input().mouseDeltaX() * 0.001);
```

apply() in the camera class is defined in an inherited class, which is called from the draw function of the game loop.

```
void apply()
        {
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
            glLoadIdentity();
            gluPerspective(40.0,(GLdouble)m_width/(GLdouble)m_height,0.5,20.0);

            m_viewPoint = m_position + m_forward;

            gluLookAt(  m_position.getX(),  m_position.getY(),  m_position.getZ(),
                        m_viewPoint.getX(), m_viewPoint.getY(), m_viewPoint.getZ(),
                        m_up.getX(),        m_up.getY(),        m_up.getZ());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't accumulate the transforms in your vectors, store the angles and generate the vectors on-the-fly.

EDIT: Floating-point stability.  Compare the output of `a` and `b`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const float small = 0.00001;
    const unsigned int times = 100000;

    float a = 0.0f;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < times; ++i )
    {
        a += small;
    }
    cout << a << endl;

    float b = 0.0f;
    b = small * times;
    cout << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.00099
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where to start, as you are posting only small snippets, not enough to fully reproduce the problem.

In your methods you update all parameters, and your parameters are depending on previous values. I am not sure what exactly you call, because you posted that you call only these two :

```
m_camera.addPitch((float)input().mouseDeltaY() * 0.001);
m_camera.addYaw((float)input().mouseDeltaX() * 0.001);
```

You should somehow break that circle by adding new parameters, and the output should depend on the input (for example, m_position shouldn't depend on m_forward).

You should also initialize all variables in the constructor, and I see you are initializing only m_forward, m_right and m_up (by the way, use initialization list).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider your approach in favor of using [quaternion rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_rotation) as described in [this paper](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~mgattass/fcg/material/shoemake92.pdf).  This has the advantage of representing all of your accumulated rotations as a single rotation about a single vector (only need to keep track of a single quaternion) which you can apply to the canonical orientation vectors (up, norm and right) describing the camera orientation.  Furthermore, since you're using C++, you can use the [Boost quaternion class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/quaternion/html/index.html) to manage the math of most of it.

Comment: I didn't realise boost had a quaternion class, yes they where my first thought but I didn't want to spend the time making a class for it (just due to the scope of the project), I'll have a look, thanks.